# For educational purposes : Need help to connect 2 switches

Tags: switch, vlan, switching

My teacher doesn't know anything about it, and I've already had to do it myself to get to this point. And he can't give me any more help.

I've tried to be as clear as possible on my diagram, I hope I'm doing it right!

Everything is explained, but if I've forgotten anything obvious, please let me know (I'm a beginner!).

[image: Diagram link image]

Comment: What does "configured as WAN" mean in this context? And, what provides communications between the bottom VLANs – is the Cisco switch actually a router or a "L3 switch"?

Comment: Have you configured the gateway for the Cisco VLANs? It should point at the OVH switch.

Comment: @u1686_grawity, the port can be declared as "LAN" or "WAN" in the interface, so I thought it was worth specifying. Yes, sorry, I meant Router, I did that last night...

Comment: @Mokubai, yeah, the default gateway is the ip adress of the interface connected on the OVH Switch

Comment: thank you for your answers guys. Sorry if I'm not very clear. My teacher has no notion of this so you contribute enormously to my knowledge. Don't hesitate to point out my mistakes.

Comment: @namiizad: Okay, but that kind of option...doesn't make any sense to _be_ on a switch. Do you happen to have screenshots of the web interface? (both the LAN/WAN option and overall)